# getInstance() Unresolved Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Showing **`getInstance()`** unresolved reference when ever call.

```
class GlobalHolder {

    private var pickerManager: PickerManager? = null

    private val ourInstance = GlobalHolder()

    fun getInstance() {
        return ourInstance
    }

    private fun GlobalHolder(){}


    fun getPickerManager(): PickerManager? {
        return pickerManager
    }

    fun setPickerManager(pickerManager: PickerManager) {
        this.pickerManager = pickerManager
    }
}
```

**Call**

```
   lateinit var pickerManager: PickerManager
    pickerManager=GlobalHolder.getInstance().getPickerManager()
```

**FYI**

This is original Java class

```
public class GlobalHolder {

    private PickerManager pickerManager;

    private static GlobalHolder ourInstance = new GlobalHolder();

    public static GlobalHolder getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private GlobalHolder() {
    }


    public PickerManager getPickerManager() {
        return pickerManager;
    }

    public void setPickerManager(PickerManager pickerManager) {
        this.pickerManager = pickerManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: `getInstance` returns `Unit` but you attempt to return a value?

Comment: @Moira he's calling the method on a class, i.e. in a static way. Won't work

Comment: A static alternative in Kotlin is a `companion object`. See this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects
But @s1m0nw1 's idea is right, if you need a singleton, better to use `object` instead of a regular class

Answer (score 6):

You're willing to have a singleton, right? Make `GlobalHolder` an [`object`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations), which will automatically provide a singleton:

```
object GlobalHolder {

    private var pickerManager: PickerManager? = null

    fun getPickerManager(): PickerManager? {
        return pickerManager
    }

    fun setPickerManager(pickerManager: PickerManager) {
        this.pickerManager = pickerManager
    }
}
```

And then your instance like this:

```
GlobalHolder.getPickerManager()
```